# .fillStyle isn't working, is their something wrong with my code? or any replacements for .fillStyle for canvases?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```js
var canvas
var canvasContext

window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Hello World");
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0 canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

I can't figure out why canvasContext.fillStyle isn't working. Any suggestions to why its not working or replacements for that function?

Comment: From review: you are missing a comma between '0'` and `canvas.width` in the last line. Voting to close as a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working. maybe a missing comma in `fillRect`?

```js
    var canvas
    var canvasContext

    window.onload = function(){
    console.log("Hello World");
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id ="gameCanvas" width="40"height="40"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yee i missed a comma after the second 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem isn't your canvas/canvasContext, but your window.onload function doesn't fire in-line, at least on stackBlitz. Do you need it to be explicitly after the window loads?

[Stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-m8f9xa?embed=1&file=index.html)

Comment: also note that I fixed the comma @Francesco mentioned. If your window.onload works, then his is probably your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There was missing a simples `,` on your `fillRect` part:

```js
var canvas
var canvasContext

window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Hello World");
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```